# SNMP4J for updating a row in an SNMP table?

Tags: snmp, snmp4j

How can I update a row from an SNMP table using the SNMP4J library? I found the method:

`TableUtils.createRow(Target target,OID rowStatusColumnOID,OID rowIndex,VariableBinding[] values)`

to create a row, but it doesn't have a method to update?

Answer (score 0):

You cant use TableUtils for that. See instead [Snmp::send](http://www.snmp4j.org/doc/org/snmp4j/Snmp.html#send%28org.snmp4j.PDU,%20org.snmp4j.Target%29) which quoting its javadoc :

> Sends a PDU to the given target and returns the received response PDU.